# Merge two directories in Linux to get all unique files

Tags: linux, merge

I have to directories, let's call them `folder1` and `folder2`. In each of these folders are images named `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` and so on.

Unfortunately, file `1.jpg` in `folder1` could be another picture than `1.jpg` in `folder2`. Furthermore it is possible that file `1.jpg` in `folder1` is the same picture as `42.jpg` in `folder2`. So I can not use the filename to distinguish these pictures.

The idea now is to use the hash instead of the filename.

The goal is to merge both folders in a third one, so that the target folder contains all unique images of both folders.

Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the names, in each folder, move the files to the target folder, renaming them after their MD5 hash:

```
for f in folder1/* folder2/*;do mv -nv "$f" target/$(md5sum -b "$f" | cut -d ' ' -f 1); done
```

`-n` is not strictly necessary, it prevents clobbering the first moved file by  a second identical file. So the net result it that with it, the duplicates are left in their source directories and you have an idea of how many dupes you had).

Then, if necessary, give them another set of arbitrary names (execute in `target`):

```
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.extension"; done
```

(one-liner above from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34153342/6378557))

Answer (score 0):

I'd run a duplicate file finder (there are many, pick your favorite) across the two folders, to reduce them to a single set of unique content.  Then a bulk rename from `*` to `folder1_*` in the first folder, similar in second, to ensure unique names.  Then merge the two with an ordinary file move.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it, to adapt a little based on your naming conventions, and you loose the original names (otherwise you need to find out what to do if you have twice the same name with different content) .

```
(for file in folder1/* folder2/* ; do md5sum $file ; done) | sort | awk '{print $2 " " $1}' | uniq -f 1 -c | while read count name hash ; do cp $name dest/$hash ; done
```

Or if you do not want to loose the original filename, just changing it:

```
(for file in folder1/* folder2/* ; do md5sum $file ; done) | sort | awk '{print $2 " " $1}' | uniq -f 1 -c | while read count name hash ; do cp $name dest/$(echo $name | sed -e 's/\//_/') ; done
```

There are a lot of assumptions done for simplicity: no paths with spaces, doing things on top of both directories, doing output in directory `dest/`etc. Many things can be fixed depending on your specific requirements but the above is a working base.